# IIS 6: Creating a HTTP 500 Error Handler in PHP

Tags: php, iis-6

There has got to be a way to configure IIS 6 to capture and redirect users when an HTTP 500 Error occurs.

I've successfully created and implemented a custom HTTP 404 Error page (very easy).  Apparently, HTTP 500 errors are not customizable (per Microsoft): http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true

What I want to do is somehow capture HTTP 500 errors and redirect to a page that logs and emails our IT support staff when a 500 error is encountered.  This is a PHP implementation, not .Net

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where specifically are you getting held up? Configuring the redirect in IIS? Writing the PHP script that handles the redirect?

Comment: I created a PHP page that emails my teammates, and modified the Custom Error for HTTP Error 500 in IIS to use this page.  When I access a PHP page deigned to throw a 500 error, my 500 error page is ignored.  I only see the standard IIS 500 error page.

Comment: great question! please let me know when there's an answer